# Cannot remove 'pgnbr' string data from corpus

Tags: python, regex, text, topic-modeling

stackoverflow-ers! I'm working to pre-process a corpus of text data with Python for a research project. I've gotten to where I need to purge the excess characters and whitespace, etc. For some reason, the code I've put together cannot purge instances of **pgnbr**  from the corpus. I've tried regex testing and just leaving the string value in, no luck. It seems like a pretty straight forward thing to do:

```
#convert to string
ocr = data_one['Ocr text'].to_string()

# regular expressions and cleaning tasks. 
import re
digit_pattern = '\d+'
whitespace_pattern = r'\s+'


clean = re.sub(digit_pattern, '', ocr)
clean = re.sub('\n', '', clean)
clean = re.sub('•', '', clean)
clean = re.sub('«', '', clean)
clean = re.sub('■', '', clean)
# struggling with correct syntax to remove pgnbr. 
clean = re.sub('pgnbr', '', clean)

# punctuation 
from string import punctuation
no_punct = ''.join([ch for ch in clean if ch not in punctuation])

# strip whitespace and lower. 
clean_text = re.sub(whitespace_pattern, ' ', no_punct)
clean_text = clean_text.strip().lower()

# tokenize 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokens = word_tokenize(clean_text)


# pgnbr string data will not go away!!! 
from collections import Counter
freq = Counter(tokens)
freq.most_common(10)

#the output of Counter
Out[225]: 
[('pgnbr', 118),
 ('the', 100),
 ('of', 68),
 ('i', 64),
 ('a', 64),
 ('to', 48),
 ('t', 38),
 ('s', 32),
 ('and', 31)]
```

Why is 'pgnbr' being so sticky?! I'm sure there's a simple answer, I just haven't found it yet.. Any help is appreciated, I can also set up a reprex if asked. Thank you Everyone!

Comment: Put the `clean = re.sub('pgnbr', '', clean)` line below `clean_text = clean_text.strip().lower()`. There are probably punctuation or whitespace chars between the letters.

Comment: OMG, thank you. It would have taken me so long to figure that out on my own. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `pgnbr` after removing all punctuation and spaces, so the cases like `p, gn, br` can still be found in the resulting string.

You should place the

```py
clean = re.sub('pgnbr', '', clean)
```

line below `clean_text = clean_text.strip().lower()`, and it should work.